How to get Google Earth to show boundary of national forests/ parks
I've been using Google Earth to map out travel routes, and find hiking areas and campsites while on vacation.
Yesterday and prior I could, for example, click on the label "Black Hills National Forest" and it would outline the border of the forest. This made it easy to see where we could camp for free.
Today I started planning some more, but when I click the same label it just makes a little red place mark at that location and shows me photos of the area.
The only difference between then and now is that I started making placemarks to show where we are/ were. I still have layers set to "everything"
I am using the mobile app. There are not that many features/ options to change.
